# What is the point of delimiters and whitespace handling

Tags: programming-languages, parsers, language-design, lexical-analysis

I see that language specifies reserved words, delimiters and whitespaces in the lexer section. Are delimiters just like reserved identifiers in the punctuation space or they have additioinal function regarding skipping the whitespace?

Namely, spec says

> Each lexical element is either a delimiter, an identifier (which may
>   be a reserved word), an abstract literal, a character literal, a
>   string literal, a bit string literal or comment. In some cases an
>   explicit separator is required to separate adjacent lexical elements
>   (namely when, without separation, interpretation as a single lexical
>   element is possible). A separator is either a space character (SPACE
>   or NBSP), a format effector, or the end of a line.

I also see a definition

```
relative_pathname ::= { ^ . } partial_pathname
```

where `.` is a delimiter but `^` is not. I do not understand why the difference. Moreover, ^ is a special character that can be only a part of `"string literal"`, `'char literal'` or `/extended identifier/` and I don't understand how to deliver this character to the path parser.

Anyway, I wonder what to do with pieces of text smashed to each other like `11'c'` or `"this is string litral"with_some_identifier`. Mine current lexer produces string_literal followed by identifier. However, I feel that others don't do that. What is the common practice for lexing and whitespace skipping -- when whitespace is it mandatory and when is it optional? How do you specify that to the parser/lexer? 
I ask because do not see that parsers/lexers specify a lot of whitespace or separators in the production rules. Despite this stuff must be ubequitos, in practice, I do not see it at all. In JavaCC, for instance, you [just specify whitespace chars in SKIP](https://javacc.java.net/doc/lexertips.html) and it does the rest itself. What is the convention? I see that [parser combinators support lexical.reserved words and lexical.delimiters](http://debasishg.blogspot.com.ee/2008/04/external-dsls-made-easy-with-scala.html). What is the purpose?

I guess that I can supplement every definition of identifier, delimiter and literal with optional whitespace prefix. Now, is it right that only identifiers and literals have to be separated by delimiters or whitespace? How do I ensure that?

Comment: Care to mention which language spec you are talking about?

Comment: I am addressing every language, the general principle. What naming the language can change? The programming languages are more or less identical. The biggest difference between C/Verilog) and Pascal/Ada/VHDL I heard of is that former need to supply ; for every statement whereas it is not necessary for the former. But this seems a parsing level. I never seen a lot of separator handling in the executable grammars. Nobody wraps separator tokens around tokens in their grammars. There must be some principle.

Comment: @rici, the only language I know which has `/extended identifier/` and bit string literal is VHDL, but I don't remember a notion of relative_pathname in it, so if it is VHDL, it is a later version than the one I was familiar 10 years ago.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov, languages tend to have their own terminology and behavior.  A "maximal-chunk" rule giving the behavior you describe is common. But there are exceptions, for instance ISTR that in VHDL attributes can be used in such a way that maximal-chunk is not what is desired. BTW, `^` was not used specially in VHDL as I remember it and you seem to confirm that.  Is it possible that it is part of the EBNF used like `{` and `}`?

Comment: @AProgrammer No, hat is used to specify external names. Read about them occasionally. The hat is used as `Upward` symbol, likewise `..` in file systems. Relative paths start from it and number of of hats specifies the parent unit you address. Probably, they have forgot to add into the delimiters. But I do not understand the principle, what are the delimiters and what should be the delimiter, and therefore I ask.

Comment: @valentin: There does not "have to be some principle". There is some agreement on maximal-munch, but there are many exceptions. C/C++ have a completely different idea of lexical numbers to other languages, so 23skidoo is a single invalid token in C and two valid tokens in many other languages...

Comment: @aprogrammer: seems plausible. Vhdl is more than usually idiosyncratic, but all languages have their idiosyncracies.

Comment: VHDL list the reserved words, delimiters and whitespaces. Combinators library allows to enter this information. It is because there is no general agreement on how to use all of that. Who are you trying to cheat?

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov, FORTRAN is (in)famous for *not* having any whitespace separating tokens, LISP dialects allow almost anything as part of an identifier, as does FORTH. And that is just more or less mainstream languages, no Intercal nor Malebogle...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now, is it right that only identifiers and literals have to be separated by delimiters or whitespace? How do I ensure that?

If by "right" you mean it is the case in every programming language, then no, it is not right, and probably no non-trivial lexical statement would be either.

In many languages, integer literals do not have to be separated from a following identifier; in other languages, they do. In most languages, `<=` is different from `< =`, so identifiers and numbers are not the only classes of tokens which require explicit separation. (If you don't consider `<` and `=` to be "delimiters", then you cannot say that identifiers need to be separated by whitespace or delimiters, either, since `a<b` is normally valid.)

Maximal munch is a very common lexical algorithm. This views the input to be a sequence of lexemes where each lexeme starts precisely following the previous lexeme and continues as far as possible (so that if two lexemes are possible at a given point in the source code, the longest one is chosen regardless of whether the rest of the input would be valid or not). Not all lexemes are tokens; the set of lexemes includes ignorable whitespace, for example, which is recognized by the tokeniser but does not otherwise participate in syntactic analysis.

However, most languages have idiosyncratic exceptions. Consider the handling of `<::` in C++ or `1..2` in D; both of these require an explicit exception to the maximal-munch rule. A different issue is the handling of regular-expression literals in ECMAscript (and other languages), in which `/` and `/=` could be tokenised as a simple operator token, or they could be the first part of a regular expression literal. Which option is chosen depends on the immediate syntactic context. Yet another deviation from the above model is found in languages like Python and Haskell where layout (whitespace used as indententation) is sometimes syntactic.

To the extent that a language specification uses the maximal munch algorithm, whitespace is mandatory *precisely* in those contexts where maximal-munch would produce a different tokenisation. In such languages, whitespace is always discarded (after tokenisation) and there is no need to ensure it is supplied.

There is no global institution which regulates computer language designers. Each language community develops according to its own philosophy, customs, eccentricities and equivocations, and there is no higher truth to which one can appeal.

---

Particular languages may be based on a different tokenisation model, so you cannot make general language-independent statements based on the behaviour of a single language. In the comments streams, it has been suggested that this question actually applies to VHDL and that VHDL does not conform to the maximal munch model. The text cited in the OP apparently comes from section 13.2 of the VHDL Reference Manual. However, it seems clear (even from the text quoted in the OP), that the design is not much different from maximal-munch. I repeat, with emphasis added:

> The text of each design unit is a sequence of separate lexical elements. Each lexical element is either a delimiter, an identifier (which may be a reserved word), an abstract literal, a character literal, a string literal, a bit string literal, or a comment.
>
> **In some cases an explicit separator is required to separate adjacent lexical elements (namely when, without separation, interpretation as a single lexical element is possible).** A separator is either a space character (SPACE or NBSP), a format effector, or the end of a line. A space character (SPACE or NBSP) is a separator except within a comment, a string literal, or a space character literal.

So that makes it clear that the only case in which separation is obligatory is where the concatenated tokens could be tokenised as a (longer) combined token, which is essentially the maximal-munch rule.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33898/discussion-on-answer-by-rici-what-is-the-point-of-delimiters-and-whitespace-hand).

Answer (score 0):

As an interesting example where white space is absolutely important is the Swift language. Take the character '-' which matches the parsing rules for operator. But is it a binary or unary operator, and if it is unary, does it bind from the left or the right?

It depends on white space: White space on the left but not on the right -> left unary (for example x = -y). White space on the right but not on the lift -> right unary (for example x = y- which is invalid because there is no right unary minus operator). White space on both sides or on neither side = binary operator (x = y-z or x = y - z, but x = y- z or x = y -z are invalid).